# How can i pass string and float value in MPAndroid bar chart

Tags: android, charts

I am using bar chart my app

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

I tried to pass x-axis value in string but it show error. is there any other options ?

Comment: *`string but it show error`* what error? share that error with question

Comment: Why dont you convert string into int or double and then pass ?

Comment: i want to pass some text

Answer (score 0):

try this code,
i hope this code is useful to you.

```
 List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < difficultyLevelCountList.size(); i++) {

                entries.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(difficultyLevelCountList.get(i).getIncorrect()),"try"));
                entries1.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(difficultyLevelCountList.get(i).getCorrect()),"try"));
                entries2.add(new BarEntry(i, Float.parseFloat(difficultyLevelCountList.get(i).getMissed()),"try"));
    }
```